# sort std::set using operator() to order the insertions

Tags: c++, sorting

I am continuing this post after [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576763/how-to-sort-a-stdset-with-const-getters)
 we have a class as:

```
class LaneConnector {
public:

    const Lane* getLaneFrom() const {
        return From;
    }
    const Lane* getLaneTo() const {
        return To;
    }

private:

    Lane* From;
    Lane* To;
}
```

and a functor to compare as:

```
struct MyLaneConectorSorter {
  bool operator() (const LaneConnector* rhs, const LaneConnector* lhs) const
  {
    // you may want to put some null pointer checks in here
    const Lane* a = lhs->getLaneFrom();
    const Lane* b = rhs->getLaneFrom();
    return a->getLaneID() < b->getLaneID();
  }
};
```

and finally a source and destination set:

```
const std::set<LaneConnector*> src = ..... ;

const std::set<LaneConnector*, MyLaneConectorSorter> dest(src.begin(), src.end(), MyLaneConectorSorter());
```

The size of the dest set will be 1 while the src has more(14 in my case)

what might have I done wrong? I value your kind comments. Thank you

Comment: There was a typo in my answer to the original problem: can you try `dest(src.begin(), src.end(), MyLaneConectorSorter())`? I had missed the `()` after `src.begin`.

Comment: @ juanchopanza Hi, that is already added so the problem is not coming from there

Comment: Do the LaneConnectors have different lane ids? Sets require unique ids, I'm not sure what happens in a set if the comparator says two keys are the same.

Comment: Show real code! If the set dest is supposed to store pointers, your comparator also needs to take pointers!

Comment: You seem to have some confusion in your comparison function with regards to right and left. It's also really bugging me that you spell `LaneConnector` with two 'n's and `MyLaneConectorSorter` with one.

Comment: @CrazyCasta: If you try to insert a new element in a set and it is already there (according to the comparer, of course), the insertion fails. It may well be what you say.

Comment: @CrazyCasta yes they have different Ids

Comment: @sellibitze the code is large. and yes the above snippt has a type. laneconnectors are passed by their pointers

Comment: @Gorpik is there any way to find out if the insertion fails?

Comment: @rahman: `insert` returns a `pair<iterator, bool>`, where the `bool` tells you whether the insertion worked or not.

Comment: @Gorpik and I dont have insert. May be I should iterate through the old set and insert into new one one by one , though not very nice looking   ?

Comment: No, of course, but what the `set` constructor does is similar. Only it does not tell you which elements were added and which were not. You can use `insert` instead of the range constructor just to see where it is failing.

Comment: @BoBTFish that is my fault. It was wrong in my answer to another question. I am left handed and often get hands mixed up.

Comment: The most likely scenario is that all your IDs are the same. Can't you print them out before making the second set?

Comment: @juanchopanza I am confused. Suppose the IDs are all same. I know the set elements are unique, but I thought the functor just stores them in order not discard them. Am I wrong?

Comment: @rahman You are wrong. ``std::set`` has unique entries, and the uniqueness is determined by the comparison function. If your IDs are duplicates, the set considers the elements to be the same.

Comment: Maybe you want a `std::multiset` instead of a `std::set`. Anyway, I cannot understand what kind of order you are expecting from `MyLaneConnectionSorter` if all IDs are the same.

Comment: @juanchopanza I got where I was going wrong. This is the duplicacy issue. So the main issue is solved, thanks to ALL of you, I will get back with some comments and will start another thread asking how to maintain a set with more than one key/ID for duplicacy checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::set` keeps track of elements based on the ***key***. In your *comparator* you have `return a->getLaneID() < b->getLaneID();`. Thus `Lane ID` implicitly becomes the ***key***. Since if `a` and `b` have the same `LaneID`, then both `MyLaneConectorSorter(a, b)` *and* `MyLaneConectorSorter(b, a)` are returning `false`.

Your `set` thus can not contain more than one `LaneConnectior` with the same `LaneID`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way to catch problems like this way before they get a chance to expose themselves. Write unit tests!

My guess is that all your LaneConnectors start at the same line. So, GetLaneFrom()->GetLaneID() yields the same result on all LaneConnectors