# how to sort a std::set using more than one key

Tags: c++, sorting, set

I need to copy a set to another one based on more than one key.
the keys are used to -collectively- maintain the uniqueness as well as  the order of elements in the set.

My class:

```
class LaneConnector {
public:

    const Lane* getLaneFrom() const {
        return From;
    }
    const Lane* getLaneTo() const {
        return To;
    }

private:

    Lane* From;
    Lane* To;
}
```

my functor:

```
struct MyLaneConectorSorter {
  bool operator() (const LaneConnector* rhs, const LaneConnector* lhs) const
  {

    const Lane* a = lhs->getLaneFrom();
    const Lane* b = rhs->getLaneFrom();

    bool key1 = a->getLaneID() < b->getLaneID();
    bool key2 = a->getLaneParent->ID() < b->getLaneParent->ID();
    bool key2 = a->getLaneParent->getParent->ID() < b->getLaneParent->getParent->ID(); 
    //remind you that I NEED the elements to be in ascending order of 
    //getLaneParent->getParent->ID() ,a->getLaneParent->ID() and then a->getLaneID()
    //duplicate elements are the ones which have all three keys same and need to be discarded 
    return (key1 && key2 && key3); //which dont seem to be working
  }
};
```

and my source and origin sets:

```
const std::set<LaneConnector*> src = ..... ; //the getter give me a const version
std::set<sim_mob::LaneConnector *, MyLaneConectorSorter> dest;
```

and how I fill it up:

```
for(std::set<sim_mob::LaneConnector*>::iterator it = tempLC.begin(); it != tempLC.end(); it++)
{
    dest.insert(*it);//I know I can insert it right at the time of declaration, but keep it like this for now...please 
}
```

your kind help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you aren't entirely clear about your ordering. By your definition you could have `A` and `B` where none of `A<B`, `B<A`, `A=B` are true.

Comment: Instead of posting [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577571/sort-stdset-using-operator-to-order-the-insertions) after [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576763/how-to-sort-a-stdset-with-const-getters), why don't you do a bit of research yourself? I think what you are looking for is [std::multiset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multiset/).

Answer (score 3):

You need to prioritorise your key field comparisons... only if the most important field is equal, then you compare the second most important - if that's equal then you compare the third most important etc..  As soon as there's an inequality, you return true or false as appropriate.  So, it's not a `&&` operation, it should be `? :` or an `if`-`else` chain, as in:

```
return lhs.key1 < rhs.key1 ? true :
       rhs.key1 < lhs.key1 ? false :
       lhs.key2 < rhs.key2 ? true :
       rhs.key2 < lhs.key2 ? false :
       ...
       false;
```

For the set to operate correctly, you must ensure the keys are never equal - so that last `false` is never actually used.

Comment: If all are equal, you **must** return false as per the contract of `operator<`.

Comment: @FredOverflow: interesting - thanks for that and answer updated; regardless, from memory it won't be sufficient to make the `set` work - doesn't the order absolutely need to be deterministic...?

Comment: @TonyDelroy: indeed: `set` needs a binary predicate conforming a 'strict weak ordering', just like `sort` and so on...

Comment: Well, `a < a` is false, that's all there is to it, really.

Answer (score 3):

Since getting `operator<` for multiple tests right is rather hard, I advocate [my way of doing this with `tuple`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6218812/500104) (in this case with `make_tuple` instead of `tie` since we're dealing with temporaries returned from functions):

```
#include <tuple>

struct MyLaneConectorSorter {
  bool operator() (const LaneConnector* lhs, const LaneConnector* rhs) const
  {
    const Lane* a = lhs->getLaneFrom();
    const Lane* b = rhs->getLaneFrom();
    auto const* pa = a->getLaneParent();
    auto const* pb = b->getLaneParent();

    return std::make_tuple(a->getLaneID(), pa->ID(), pa->getParent()->ID()) < 
           std::make_tuple(b->getLaneID(), pb->ID(), pb->getParent()->ID())
}
```

This should work and you can get `tuple` and `make_tuple` from Boost too, if your compiler doesn't offer them yet.

Comment: Yes!  and following the DRY motto and the SRP principle, you could make a method to convert the `lhs` to a `tuple`.

Comment: @xtofl: Not necessarily convert, but `get_comparision_tuple` out of the `LaneConnector`. :)

Comment: @Xeo very cool Xeo, anyway, my compiler doesn't support tuple and I have to use boost. When I build the program, it says: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘boost::tuples::make_tuple  . any solution to that?

Comment: @rahman: For Boost.Tuple, you need to `#include <boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp>` for the relational operators to be available.

Answer (score 2):

If you have three member foo, bar and baz to compare on, this is a common way to compare them:

```
return lhs.foo < rhs.foo
    || lhs.foo == rhs.foo && (lhs.bar < rhs.bar
                           || lhs.bar == rhs.bar && lhs.baz < rhs.baz);
```

Do you see the pattern? ;)

Comment: +1: that's actually the way I usually do it, but thought the more verbose approach in my answer easier for a beginner to follow....

Answer (score 1):

I have problem understanding your sorting rules, but if the relation is a simple sub-sort than the code should look like this:

```
if (a->getLaneID() < b->getLaneID())
  return true;
else if (a->getLaneID() == b->getLaneID())
{
  if (a->getLaneParent->ID() < b->getLaneParent->ID())
    return true;
  // etc...
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `class MyLaneConnectionSorter` has a flaw.

`std::set` expects a comparison class that can order elements. So your comparison function must provide behaviour similar to `less` functor or `operator<`, i.e. either `a < b` or `a > b` (which is `b < a`) or `a == b` (which is `!(a < b) && !(a > b)`)

If we take your comparison function, it will consider Lanes (6, 5, 4) and (7, 3, 4) (in format (PPID, PID, ID)) to be equal, because neither one is less than another. So you need to compare like this:

```
if (a->getLaneParent->getParent->ID() < b->getLaneParent->getParent->ID()) return true;
else if (a->getLaneParent->getParent->ID() > b->getLaneParent->getParent->ID()) return false;
else {
    if (a->getLaneParent->ID() < b->getLaneParent->ID()) return true;
    else if (a->getLaneParent->ID() > b->getLaneParent->ID()) return false;
    else {
        return (a->getLaneID() < b->getLaneID());
    }
}
```